# How to fetch compressed image from File Manager in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, grand-central-dispatch, file-manager

I am creating custom Photo Library using UICollectionViewController. Images are save to File Manager using AVFoundation (custom camera). It is working well & save images to File Manager.

Now, I want to load all captured images to UICollectionView. Image size is very high, so UICollectionView getting very very slow.

**I am also using prefetching.**

I want compressed image up to 20 KB to 30 KB(enough to display) to show in UICollectionView.

My question is, **How to get compressed image(~30KB) from File Manager(~5 to 10MB, sometimes 15MB)?**

**Is necessary to save 2 types of images(Original & Compressed)?**

> But I don't want to save 2 types of images because it's taking memory.

Also used NSCache using extension, but still CollectionView is very slow.

```
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

    var id: String?

    //imageID coming from CoreData
    func loadImage(imageID: String) {

        id = imageID
        image = nil

        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: imageID as NSString) {
            self.image = imageFromCache
            print("already loaded \(imageID)")
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            //FileManager Extension
            let url = FileManager.itemUrl(itemID: "\(imageID)").path
            if let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url) {
                if self.id == imageID {
                    self.image = img
                }
                imageCache.setObject(img, forKey: imageID as NSString)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Extension for File Manager

```
public extension FileManager {

    static var documentDirectoryURL: URL {
        return try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    }

    static func itemUrl(itemID: String) -> URL {
        return documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(itemID).png")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do it during the saving, save a H-Res image and compress and save a "Low-Res" image, then load only the low-res images and the H-Res when needed.

Comment: First, I don't want to save both images because of memory issue. Second, is this only way to solve the problem? How Apple Photos app work?

Comment: Your collection view cell size should dynamic, when you resize the image it effects on performance.

Comment: Apples Photos app likely uses the Photos framework, or a private version of it. The Photos framework [PHImageManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager) can be used to generate and cache thumbnails of the images.

Comment: So, Apple is storing only one original image and compressed when thumbnails generation?

Comment: I check with this link https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/PhotoTransitioning/Introduction/Intro.html Apple is getting 3 types of Images : low quality (~10 to 20 KB), Medium quality (~100 KB) and Original image when preview image(single image). So, in this demo are they store 3 types of images or only original image & get different as required?